# moving file to ntfs volume

Tags: dual-boot, disk

I have a nfts disk that I use to keep movies and music: on ubuntu, I created a folder onto this disk and moved a video file from my ext4 disk to that folder. Turned out I could not access to the folder on windows 7. Is this some kind of permission-related problem? Can sombody help to set the disk in order to receive and run files from either os?

Comment: ok..turned out that if the folder is created on ubuntu, it cannot be read by windows, at least that particolar one...so I created the same folder on windows and then i moved the file from the previous folder to the new one (on ubuntu). The file is now visible and playable on windows...this is not  "solved" but at least I got my file back.

Comment: If you suspect permission related problems, you should provide informations about the permissions of that folder!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid that you moved the file with root permission. It also happens when you format your ntfs disk from ubuntu. Ubuntu does not give enough permission by default. Install ntfs-config. Give Internal and External writer permission to ntfs partition using ntfs-config. And also change your moved files permission

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /media/ntfsdiskname/
```